# MongoDB insert wrong data

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm updating data to MongoDB database but I'm getting an unexpected bug. Everything works perfectly if I send update request to database at normal speed, but when I try to another situation which is spamming multiple requests to the database in a short period of time and this cause to my data updated in database is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
const hasUserExists = await likeCollection.exists({ user_id: user_id}); 

if (!hasUserExists) {
    await likeCollection.create({ post_id: post_id, user_id: user_id });
}
else {
    await likeCollection.findOneAndDelete({ post_id: post_id, user_id: user_id });
}
```

Above code returns unexpected result with the same duplicated documents:

```
[
  {
    "post_id" : 123,
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "post_id" : 123,
    "user_id": 1
  }
]
```

I don't think my code has problem, I am confused to find the problem. Can someone help me understand the problem i am facing?

Comment: What specifically are you changing when you "spam multiple requests to the database in a short period of time"? Running multiple instances of the code?

Comment: @user20042973 I mean I make many requests continuously request to the server to update data in a short period of time from frontend. That causing my MongoDB database not updating correctly. I still haven't found a solution to this problem, help me!

Comment: I am still waiting for mark answer

Comment: @Epple If you have access to the DB and the Backend try to log all the requests made to the DB. The DB itself is ACID compliant. So you most likely have a race condition or the request did not go through.

Comment: @Epple It could also be that it created the user twice which means that your condition `if (!hasUserExists) {` fails. Put a console.log inside both the if and else cases and check where it goes through - alternatively use a debugger tool.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be OK,maybe could you have forgotten to await the code that's wrapping the code you posted.

Comment: no, I was checked my code again, I don't think that's the cause

Comment: This should have been a comment as it's a guess and not written as an answer.